# How to go about SLAM & Navigation in ROS Melodic?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, rviz, slam

I have a 4 wheeled robot with a LiDAR that is using the skid steer plugin using ROS Melodic. At the moment I can move the robot (using teleop keyboard) in Gazebo and see the robot's movement and laserScan points in RViz with no issues.

At the moment I am only doing simulations but I will be working on real robot soon for work that is meant to move about within a space that might have some obsticales and draw some lines very precisely. I believe the robot that I will be working on has very precise movement as the wheel encoders are 10k per rev of the wheel.

The issue I have here is that I am very new to ROS and have no idea on how to get started with SLAM and Navigation. All the tutorials and guides I have been looking at have either used ROS2 or skipped some steps in the setting up of the robot for SLAM. My robot publishes `/scan` and `/odom` messages and takes `/cmd_vel` messages to but I am not sure what else is needed in terms of preparations and what packages to use for SLAM.

Some guidance on this topic would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ROS1 or ROS2? Do you want to integrate an existing ROS package that offers SLAM functionality?

Comment: @skpro19 I am using ROS 1 but I don't really know much about SLAM so I guess I want to use an existing package the offers SLAM. But i asked on reddit too and they suggested that I move to ROS 2 as there's more support for it and better SLAM packages too. So I think that might be the best option as I am new to ROS so i could do with the support and long term support is needed for the project too. If you know about SLAM in ROS 2 some suggestions for high precision SLAM & Navigation would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the ROS1 `gmapping` package?

Comment: I did very briefly but because I am so new to ROS I don't really understand what's going on with it and I am short on time. From what I have seen in tutorials ROS 2 slam toolbox and Nav2 seems much easier to use and simpler to get into for a noob like me.